# hive-server2 creates a new thread that never exits every time I launch a query

Tags: hive, apache-zookeeper

I'm investigating a strange issue with hive-server2. Each time I launch a query, hive-server2 creates a new thread.

```
 # I'm seeing the output of this command augmenting each time I launch a query
 ps -eLF | grep hive HiveServer2 | wc -l
```

Sooner or later the machine hive-server2 is running on runs out of memory and I can't launch queries any more.

From what I can see, this issue can be related to Zookeeper. Each hive-server2 thread opens a connection to zookeeper (I'm using hive.support.concurrency=true. that's what zookeeper is used for with hive). In Zookeeper's log I'm seeing these messages:

```
2014-04-25 15:01:32,278 [myid:] - INFO  
[ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@627] - 
Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14598934389005c 
type:create cxid:0x1 zxid:0xbfc0 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a 
Error Path:/hive_zookeeper_namespace 
Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hive_zookeeper_namespace
```

Please, help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the property "hive.server2.enable.doAs"  in hive-site.xml

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.3.0/bk_releasenotes_hdp_1.x/content/ch_relnotes-hdp1.3.0_5_hive.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I deleted the /hive_zookeeper_namespace at the zookeeper and it seems to work fine.